# How to get a value from JavaScript function from button in page load?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have a button with a function like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="BTN_Export" runat="server" Text="Export to *.xlsx" OnClientClick="return IfClicked();"/>
```

And my function JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function IfClicked() {

            return Yes;
        }
    </script>
```

If i clicked on this button i want to get value yes in page load like...

```
Dim Click As String = Nothing

Click = BTN_Export.OnClientClick.ToString
```

But is not work like that, I want to get my function value in Page_Load

Comment: So which language are you working in, VBA or VB.NET?

Comment: Is for vb.net, i can convert the code